# uiTableView in uiViewController: something's missing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I need a toolbar underneath my table so here I am.

xcode 7.3.1
Swift 2

I've got a Table View added to a basic View Controller.

I dragged the `delegate` and `datasource` outlets from the table view to the view controller in storyboard.

I dragged a table cell to my table view. I set my `reuseIdentifier` to "cell"

I set the cell type to Details
Table type is Plain

Here's my customized View Controller class (it has explanatory comments throughout):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire
class ScheduleViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    let cellIdentifier = "cell" // also tried: let cellIdentifier = "cellIdentifier"
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
   var Titles:Array< String > = Array < String >()
   var Details:Array< String > = Array < String >()
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       var height = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
       var insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: height, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    /* if any of the following four lines are not commented out it throws an error after successful build, in simulator: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value */
    // self.tableView.contentInset = insets 
    // self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets 
    // self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.grayColor(); 
    // self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;
      manager.request(.POST, getUrl(), parameters:["dev": 1]).responseJSON {response in
            print(response)
            var json = JSON(response.result.value!);
            print(json)
            if !json["logged_in"]
            {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginController", sender: self)
                return;
            }
            for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["shifts"]
            {
                self.Titles.append(subJson["title"].string!);
                self.Details.append(subJson["detail"].string!);
            }
            // everything in this async function goes swimmingly until the next line
            self.do_table_refresh(); 
            // see do_table_refresh function for error detail
       }
   }
    func do_table_refresh()
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
           self.tableView.reloadData() /* < this line here throws the same error as the four lines mentioned above: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value." it builds fine (no error indicated until the simulator gets to the point of running the function) */                 
           return
       })
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return Titles.count
   }    
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
       cell.textLabel?.text = Titles[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = Details[indexPath.row]
       if Details[indexPath.row] == "OFF"
        {
            cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor(red: 214/255, green: 214/255, blue: 214/255, alpha: 1)
            cell.detailTextLabel!.textColor = UIColor(red: 214/255, green: 214/255, blue: 214/255, alpha: 1)
        }
       else
       {
            cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
           cell.detailTextLabel!.textColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
       }
      return cell
    }
}
```

These functions all work fine when I'm using a TableView Controller, but I need a toolbar.

Any one of the following five lines (the first four found in the `viewDidLoad` function and last in the `do_table_refresh` function), the app will fail (after successful build) with: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

```
   // self.tableView.contentInset = insets
   // self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
   // self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.grayColor();
   // self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;

   // self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Back in the Table View Controller, these lines don't give me that error, so I'm assuming something is empty in tableView.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: what has the toolbar got something to do with your separator?

Comment: No. The toolbar is for nav and other options for the table. There is no code related to the toolbar in this class. I just need to use the UIView because you cannot add a toolbar to a UITableView.

Comment: can't you drag and drop a toolbar in?

Comment: Not into a TableView Controller. No. Table View Controllers take up the full page by design, which is why a million people have stack overflow questions about adding a Table View to a standard View Controller.

Comment: yes i know, but you are using UIViewController and not UITableViewController, which makes it possible to drag and drop a toolbar in.

Comment: The problem is not the toolbar. The toolbar is not the issue. I switched to UIView so I can use the toolbar. But in doing so, the table stopped working. As explained above.

Comment: your question is very misleading. anyway I've answered. try and let me know the result.

Comment: "I need a toolbar underneath my table so here I am" is an insider statement for those who are familiar with the everpresent problem of not being able to drag a toolbar to the TableView Controller. The entire rest of the question makes explicit what my actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your viewDidLoad() method, you need to add the delegate and dataSource to link your table to the view controller.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     tableView.delegate = self
     tableview.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: avoid using tableView as your variable name. change when connecting to your IBOutlet to something more descriptive. Like loginTableView.

Comment: No, I've already tried this solution several hours ago. Doesn't work. And I've already assigned those in the class declaration anyway, in addition to assigning them in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
     self.do_table_refresh(); 
 })
```